# ¿Como especifico esta relación en mi proyecto de spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo esta relación donde la clave principal de publications depende de la clave principal de teacher_profile_post y funciona como clave principal y foránea, nose cómo representarla en spring boot.

Este es el codigo de teacher_profile_post:

```
public class TeacherProfilePost {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;//tipo objetuales no primitivos

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "teacherProfilePost", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Publication publication;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
private Student student;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id")
private Teacher teacher;}
```

Este es el codigo de publications solo me faltaria especificar la relación:

```
public class Publication {




@OneToOne(mappedBy = "publication", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private CommentReport commentReport;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
private Publication parent;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String comment;

@Column(nullable = false)
private int like;

@Column(nullable = false)
private int dislike;}
```

Comment: Pon todas las tablas que tienes y como estan relacionada porque de ese dibujo no se entiede nada. tengo tabla profesores y se relaciona un a varios con los alumnos por ej

Comment: Amigo, me refiero solamente a como poder hacer en spring boot que la clave principal de publication sea la misma de teacherprofile sin necesidad de crear una nueva en publication y como la represento en spring boot, he intentado de varias maneras pero no me funciona. Los campos de teacherprofile y publication son solo de referencia pero no es el problema, espero que esta orientación te sirva.

Comment: esk en publication no tienes clave principal ponle una id a algum campo ponle 
Id
GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;//tipo objetuales no primitivos